# Cannot Create Database with credentials using Entity Framework Code-First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, code-first

I'm a bit new to code-first approach but I used Database first approach before using entity framework, now I want to work with code first instead and its kinda a habit.

I started creating models and its all good, then enabled migrations and add-migration as well and all works well, but when I run Update-Database command I get an error.

Hence I want to create a database with code-first using credentials, after a lot of research I didn't find a solution and mostly tutorials use "Trusted Connection".

What I use

App.Config

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CodeFirst" connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=CodeFirst;User ID=anyuser;Password=anypassword;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

DbContext Class

```
public class CodeFirstContext : DbContext
    {
        public CodeFirstContext() : base("name=CodeFirst")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    }
```

The Error I get

```
Login failed for user 'anyuser'.
```

The question is I did something wrong ? or using credentials can't be done using code-first approach ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP:

> I want to **create a database** with **code-first** using **credentials**,

...and:

> after a lot of research I didn't find a solution and mostly tutorials use "Trusted Connection".

Therein lies the problem with *code-first approaches when deploying to a new database using a specific login* - it's a **chicken and egg** because:

1. the database doesn't yet exist
2. the connection string is requesting an explicit login
3. the login does not yet exist in say SQL
4. because the database doesn't exist

OP's config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CodeFirst" 
         connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=CodeFirst;User ID=anyuser;Password=anypassword;" 
      ... />
  </connectionStrings>
```

So what's the solution?

1. **Use Integrated Security:** this allows you to create the database from scratch from code.  However any other logins you may need might have to be created later.  However, DB-speaking, it's a bit of a bad practice because you should get into the habbit of having one account for deployment (with just enough rights for deployment) and another for general app access (and no rights for deployment)
2. **Create Login First:** this allows you to use your specified login however you most likely will need to create a *blank* database first from SQL before you can create the login.  Code-first purists may not like this idea.

The latter does follow DACPAC best practices you should already be familiar with from your time in database-first.  Just like how a DACPAC shouldn't be deploying logins and adjusting security neither should code-first.   Afterall at the end of the day, databases don't care about whether you use code-first or database-first (under the hood, both probably employ some form of encasulated scripting) but your DB Admin might raise an eyebrow depending on how security is being used.

### Are database-first approaches better?

In the theme of *[don't do that, try this instead](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)*, code-first tries to do everything via code and whilst a noble pursuit perhaps isn't realistic.  Some things like attempting to create logins perhaps isn't possible as mentioned above.

Meanwhile database-first schema changes are carried out by deploying DACPACs from the database side.  Authentication is via the login used to get into SSMS (for example) in the first place. DACPAC deployment doesn't require code, .NET or otherwise.

DACPACs can create and/modify database security including logins but is generally frowned upon.

You might want to re-think code-first.  Code-first and EF Migrations hasn't really succeeded as a concept in the real world where you have staged CD environments such as DEV; TEST; UAT and PROD.

I see so many developers using **code-first only** for deploying to their **local database**.  Once there, they use **different means** to deploy the changes to other computers including **TEST and PROD** whether it's TSQL scripts or database backup.

It just seems to be so much effort for something that doesn't even complete the race.

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback and really appreciate, the two solutions you provided I actually used the 1st one before as you see in the question I talked about "Trusted Connection" which will turn into Integrated Security itself and I see some security issues with it when it comes to production, the 2nd solution comes almost with Code-First from existing database which leads to scaffolding and not everybody likes reversing the database and  I don't see the point for code-first when the database already exist.

Comment: @Null you're welcome.  Yes exactly right, code-first is great for green-fields.  However, EF code-first is very much like how MS handled XML SOAP Services.  They also did a code-first approach and the compiler spat out WSDL after the fact. Then people wondered why nothing spoke with XML SOAP services in the much larger EAI Java space.   In these two cases, schema-first is the better approach.  Don't forget to _accept as answer/upvote_ above answer if you feel so

Comment: My main purpose for using Code-First approach was to be able to move for EF Core as this one only supports code-first, but it seems this costs security which I don't prefer at all in that case.

Comment: @Null ah ok.  It might be short-lived too as .NET 5 (which is open-source and cross platform) is coming out end of year with MS returning to a single framework once again. There will no longer be .NET Core xxx including of course EF Core.  However it does remain to be seen what will be happening in the database-first/code-first space.  Wishing you well and thanks for accept! :)

Comment: @MicyD Thanks a lot for the information you provided for the answer and about .NET 5 that was new to me and I didn't know about it, Thanks once again.